# Ruby on Rails - Should I separate the dashboard for each use type or just have one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm setting up my first rails application and I have a question for an experienced developer. I use devise for my user authentication system. I'm not up on the verbiage yet, so forgive me.

The user will have a dashboard when they log in. Is it better to use the generate scaffold tool to setup a single controller for the dashboard (and use if statements to differentiate), or create the dashboard page under the /students and /teachers (having two separate controllers)?

I'm looking to avoid wasting time or having to backtrack my application if I notice one method won't allow me to achieve something down the road. I'm leaning towards separating them.

Here is my rake routes for you to see how I've got stuff setup so far:

```
rake routes
                     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
              landing_index GET    /landing/index(.:format)          landing#index
        new_teacher_session GET    /teachers/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            teacher_session POST   /teachers/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_teacher_session DELETE /teachers/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           teacher_password POST   /teachers/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_teacher_password GET    /teachers/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_teacher_password GET    /teachers/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                            PATCH  /teachers/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                            PUT    /teachers/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_teacher_registration GET    /teachers/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       teacher_registration POST   /teachers(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_teacher_registration GET    /teachers/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_teacher_registration GET    /teachers/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                            PATCH  /teachers(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                            PUT    /teachers(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                            DELETE /teachers(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
        new_student_session GET    /students/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            student_session POST   /students/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_student_session DELETE /students/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           student_password POST   /students/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_student_password GET    /students/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_student_password GET    /students/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                            PATCH  /students/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                            PUT    /students/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_student_registration GET    /students/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       student_registration POST   /students(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_student_registration GET    /students/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_student_registration GET    /students/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                            PATCH  /students(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                            PUT    /students(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                            DELETE /students(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                       root GET    /                                 landing#index
```

So again, do you think it's better to have both the student's dashboard and the teacher's dashboard be separate, or just have one dashboard and use if statements to differentiate based on the user's type (using 0 & 1 to indicate whether they are a student or teacher)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If the data that you want to display to each type of user are similar, you could use the same controller and load different partials based on the type of the user.

Comment: That's what I'm leaning towards. A google search on partials gave me the docs for render which looks good: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

But from your experience, is the suggested method BETTER than having separate controllers in the long run? I guess a better question would be - Would you use this method over the other proposed?

Comment: I don't like the idea of exposing the difference of logic to the end user by providing different RESTful urls. I would go with the different partials solution and if the logic differs so much I would use presenters that would fetch the proper data and serve them to the views.

Comment: Awesome, I'll start reading and playing around. Appreciate your time Tasos.